# Compile dynamically created HTML to existing component

Tags: angular

I have a component, in which there is a 3rd party library that inserts the following HTML to the DOM:

`<input (click)="doSomething()"/>{{someText}}`

`doSomething` is a function in my component, and `{{someText}}` is a property.

I'm trying to figure out a way to compile this string to the existing component, and not create a new one with `ComponentFactoryResolver`.

I've tried to append the dynamic HTML and then use `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`, or `NgZone.run(callback)` or `ApplicationRef.tick()`. None of these compiled the HTML.

Any ideas?

Comment: You really need to change your strategy. An angular application, in production, is (or at least should be) compiled with the AOT compiler, precisely to make things much faster, and allow not delivering the angular compiler with the application, making it also smaller. So, compiling things at runtime is not even possible anymore. You can of course decide not to do that, but you'll be fighting against the framework and its best practices.

Answer (score 0):

What about using [ViewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createEmbeddedView):

Template:

```
<!-- location in your component template to add the dynamic template -->
<ng-container #ref></ng-container>

...

<!-- dynamic template definition -->
<ng-template #tpl>
  <input (click)="doSomething()"/>{{someText}}
</ng-template>
```

Component Class:

```
someText: string;

@ViewChild('ref')
vcr: ViewContainerRef; 

@ViewChild('tpl')
tpl: TemplateRef;

ngOnInit() {

  myLib.onSomeEvent(() => {
    this.vcr.createEmbeddedView(this.tpl); 
  })
}

doSomething() {
  ...
}
```